# how to break loop from for and form a string value again?

Tags: apex, for

I have map which size is 10.from the Map from each 3 keys i have to form a string.
then the string is set to empty.from the next (3 to 6) map keys again i want to form a string.
Please guide me

Apex class

```
String strval='';

Integer incrementer=0;


for(String strId:mapVal.keyset()){

    incrementer++
    if(strval== ''){
             strval= '\'' + strId+ '\'';
    } else {
             strval+= ',\'' + strId+ '\'';
    }   


    if(incrementer==3){
        system.debug('strval******'+strval);
        break;
    }
}
```

Eg

```
mapVal={01='apple'},{02='banaa'},{03='mango'},{04='cat'},{05='dog'}
```

for the first time if map size until 3 i want like this

`strval=applebanaamango`

After that

```
strval=catdog
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code. Result of this concatenation would be return by method.

```
private List<String> getConcatanetedValues(Map<String, String> mapToProcess, Integer count){
    List<String> result = new List<String>();
    String tempValue = '';
    for(Integer i=0; i<mapToProcess.values().size(); i++){
        String value = mapToProcess.values().get(i);
        tempValue+=value;
        if(Math.mod(i, count) == count-1) {
            result.add(tempValue);
            tempValue = '';
        }
    }
    if(String.isNotBlank(tempValue)){
        result.add(tempValue);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Usage:

```
Map<String, String> mapValues = new Map<String, String>{
    '01' => 'apple',
    '02' => 'banana',
    '03' => 'mango',
    '04' => 'cat',
    '05' => 'dog'
};
System.debug(getConcatanetedValues(mapValues, 3));
```

//DEBUG|(applebananamango, catdog)